# Is there a real widescreen patch for Warcraft 3?

Tags: warcraft-3

Is there a *"real"* widescreen patch or hack for Warcraft 3 to e.g. allow playing in 16:10/1680x1050?

The only solutions I've found (like changing the resolution in the registry) give me either 4:3 with black bars or stretch to 16:10.

Comment: Wc 3 has many resolutions in his options. Hacks are not needed anymore.  I get my res 1920x1080 without a problem. Are 16:10 specifically not supported??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to play it in widescreen with the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: Sad but true! :(

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the resolution in the registry (CURRENT_USER/Software/Blizzard Entertainment/Warcraft III/Video, reswidth and resheight).

The 3d parts will be expanded, but the 2d parts like the HUD will be stretched a bit.
As far as I know no real ways to allow you to use the extra wideness.

Comment: Nope, it stretches the full screen, see e.g. the screenshots [here](http://www.widescreengamingforum.com/wiki/Warcraft_III:_Reign_of_Chaos).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Blizzard added support for widescreen resolutions in patch version 1.25b. You can get it [here](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/classic-game-patches).

Comment: The widescreen resolutions show up, but the graphics don't appear to scale correctly.  They stretch wide instead of extending the view.